# Scrollable Perfectly Symmetrical ImageButtons in XML Android

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

In my Android app, I want to create a scrollable grid of images that have the same width/height. I don't want to use GridView because there will not be that many images. So far, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/food"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/music" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/offcampus"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/sports" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It is very close to what I want to achieve, but the second LinearLayout (the one with the layout_height of 0dp) causes the first two ImageButtons to take up the majority of the screen, so that the user has to scroll a lot to see the next two ImageButtons. In other words, there is way too much space between "rows" of images. Is there any way I can fix this?

I attached a picture in case there was confusion.

[image]
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We'll have to check if the extra space is due to the `LinearLayout` being too tall or if the `ImageButton`s themselves are. You can use "Dump View Hierarchy" button in the ADT in eclipse's Devices view. I suspect it's the `ImageButton`s using the images' original height. See if setting `android:adjustViewBounds` on the `ImageButton`s help with the issue.

Comment: Wow, that fixed it! Thank you so much. If you would like to repost your comment as the answer, I would be happy to upvote and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the extra space is due to the `LinearLayout` being too tall or if the `ImageButton`s themselves are. You can use *"Dump View Hierarchy"* button in the ADT in Eclipse's *Devices* view.

I suspect it's the `ImageButton`s using the images' original height. See if setting `android:adjustViewBounds` on the `ImageButton`s help with the issue. See reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds